# MySQL INSERT using variables from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables whose ID's I want to compare using SQL databases from WordPress.

The following works fine:

```
INSERT INTO entries(author_name) 
SELECT meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = "user_submit_name" AND post_id = '5235';
```

But what I want to do is compare the ID's from the tables entries and wp_postmeta anytime the ID's are the same, like this:

```
INSERT INTO entries(author_name) 
SELECT meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = "user_submit_name" AND post_id = entries.post_id;
```

But the above doesn't work. 
Is it possible to do this in one line, or do I have to create a procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, you just have to use a join.

```
INSERT INTO entries(author_name) 
SELECT meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta
JOIN entries on wp_postmeta.post_id = entries.post_id
WHERE meta_key = "user_submit_name" AND post_id = entries.post_id;
```

This will insert the meta_value into entries where ever there is post_id in the entries table that has a match in wp_postmeta.  This means if you run the insert statement twice you will try to do the same insert twice.  If this is a problem, we can add a sub select to not insert duplicate records.  Additionally, if there is more than one entries with the same post id we will have the same issue.  However, the given sql statement should work for a single run where the entries post_id is unique for the entries table.

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't believe I wasn't using JOIN (I'm a noob). Unfortunately, this adds extra rows with the author_name value filled and everything else null rather than changing. Should I be using UPDATE instead?

Comment: Once again, thanks to both of you!

Here's the code that ended up working:
UPDATE entries JOIN wp_postmeta SET author_name = wp_postmeta.meta_value WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_ket = "user_submit_name" AND poem_id = wp_postmeta.post_id;

So yeah, had to combine both of y'all's advice.